# How to launch com.google.android.gms.auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN from Android browser

Tags: android-intent, android-browser, google-authentication

I am looking into [app-based Google authentication](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/). Is it possible to launch the same activity (via the `Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent`) from a browser as you do from a mobile app?

If you use a browser to use Google sign-in, then you will automatically use the [web-based Google authentication](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/). But I would like to use the mobile application when users are going to my website from a mobile browser on Android.

I know it's possible to launch intents from the Android browser but I'm unsure if it is also possible to launch the Google sign-in intent *and* have the reply returned to a webpage (a callback webpage if you will).

So let's split this up in two parts:

- Is it possible to launch the Google sign-in activity?
- Is it possible to get the reply from such an activity delivered to a web application?

Edit: Comments on the feasibility are also welcome. If there are strong arguments why this isn't possible, they can also form an accepted answer.

Comment: "*But I would like to use the mobile application when users are going to my website from a mobile browser on Android.*" Even if it's possible, why? Is your web application exclusive to Android? (iOS and Windows won't be able to login since there's no meaning to `Intent`)

Comment: I would default to the web application if the browser is not supporting intents (is not an Android browser). It's a business requirement to use the native app if possible. If it's possible it's not hard to use the webapp if the native app isn't supported. The question is, is it possible to launch that sign-in intent and receive the response in a web application?

Comment: To answer your 'why' question. If you use the mobile application, the mobile device' session will be reused. In most cases people are signed in to Google on their mobile device so this sign-on will happen seamless while they would required to fill in their credentials (if not already authenticated with Google in the browser) when using the web application.

Comment: As i understand it, the browser would have to start the activity for a result, (which is different than just launching an activity) and then somehow return that result to your website. Considering the wide variety of things an activity can return this seems like its not likely something a browser might do. If you have an app already your best bet would probably be to deep link into your own app, have that launch the google play activity to sign the user in, and have the user continue using your app instead of the browser.

Comment: JStephen, thanks for the comments. The activity could communicate the response by means of a 'callback' URL back to the web application. I don't have an app already.